# How do I return a variable from $.post() in jQuery? Closure variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

I am having trouble passing data retrieved from a $.post() function to use in other places in my code.  I want to save the data as a variable and use it outside of the post() function. This is my code:

```
var last_update = function() {
$.post('/--/feed',
{func:'latest', who:$.defaults.login},
function($j){
            _j = JSON.parse($j);    
            alert(_j.text); // This one works    
        });
}
alert(_j.text); // This one doesn't
};

last_update(); //run the function
```

Please help!

Comment: In your second alert `_j` is `undefined`, so `_j.text` is attempting to access a property on `undefined`, which fails. Do you have a particular need to run code outside of the AJAX callback, instead of placing it inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data value outside of the ajax request callback, you will need to place that code in a function, and call it from the success callback.

```
var last_update = function() {
$.post('/--/feed',
{func:'latest', who:$.defaults.login},
function($j){
            _j = JSON.parse($j);    
            alert(_j.text); // This one works   
            someOtherFunc(_j.text); 
        });
}
};

last_update(); //run the function

function someOtherFunc(val) {
    alert(val)
}
```

Essentially the same as placing the code in the callback, but can be useful if you have a bit of code that is reused elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `$.post()` AJAX call is asynchronous - this means that the AJAX request is made out-of-order of usual program execution, and in your program that means that the second alert is called before _j is populated. The order of execution is:

1. call last_update()
2. make the ajax request, remember to execute the callback function but not now
3. call the second alert(_j.text);
4. when the ajax request returns data, execute the callback function

Move the code that utilises the AJAX return data to the `success()` function (which is your return function `function($j)` here) - that what the success function is for.

`$.post()` is an aliased call to `$.ajax()` - full docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks, what I want to know is how to use the returned data outside of the success function. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to move the code that utilises the AJAX return data to the `success()` function - the data isn't returned to the script until that stage

Answer (score 0):

You could make your POST request synchronous and have a global _j variable:

```
// global!!!
var _j;

$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: '/--/feed',
  data: { func:'latest', who:$.defaults.login },
  success: function($j) {
    _j = JSON.parse($j);    
    alert(_j.text); // This one works
  }
});

function last_update() {
  if (typeof _j != 'undefined') {
    alert(_j);
  }
}
```

Or you could simply call last_update() from within your success callback, thereby no longer requiring async:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/--/feed',
  data: { func:'latest', who:$.defaults.login },
  success: function($j) {
    _j = JSON.parse($j);    
    alert(_j.text); // This one works
    last_update(_j);
  }
});

function last_update(_j) {
    alert(_j);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create `_j` in the scope of the `last_update` function.

Comment: It looks like _j is a global.  But the problem is the async nature, not the scope.

Comment: I thought his question was how to make _j into a closure variable.

Comment: @Peter. Based on the OP's response to Andy, it looks like I interpreted it correctly, though I admit I didn't explain why his example didn't work.